# Zoho CRM Client Script: How to access "modify time" of loaded page

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge

I'm writing a Zoho CRM Client script for the Account-Edit-onSave event. I'd like to access the "modify time" property such as it was when the user loaded the page, is this possible?

I've tried using `$Page.record._Modify_time` but it looks like this returns what is on the server when the user presses "save", not what it was when the user loaded the page, so if someone else had modified the same record while the user was looking at the page, I'd get the updated "modify time", not the original one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$Page.record._Last_Activity_time`, it same as the Modified Time.

Comment: This returns what is on the server when the user presses "save", not what it was when the user loaded the page.